# List structure changing while iterating

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am using the following code to iterate over a linked list

```
void display()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    struct node *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {

        printf("%3c", current->data); // *(current).data

        current = current->next; // current = *(current).next;

    } //printf( "\n" );
    printf("%3c", current->data);
    printf("    <-->  ");
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%3c", current->data); // *(current).data
        current = current->prev;      // current = *(current).prev;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault in this function and I am unable to figure
out why that could be happening. 
I ran debugger and took screenshots: 
[image] 
[image]


 The above two images are from withing the call to display when it iterating
over the while loop. The weird thing is in the first image
the elements are Y->O->R->x->K 
whereas when the iteration continues in the while loop 
After encountering `R` the next data is strangely some `\000`
I never inserted that one and also how did it change withing

 the same iteration as there is no modification happening

***Minimal Reproducible code:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
#define MAX_LEN 30
char get(int index);
int search(char);
struct twoInts
{
    int int1;
    int int2;
};

struct node
{ // list 'node' struct
    char data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

void init();
void display();

struct node *head;

int main()
{
    int index;
    char key;

    struct twoInts *arr[MAX_LEN];
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    init();

    int i = 0;
    int summation[10] = {89, 79, 82, 75, 85, 76, 65, 66, 83};
    for (; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int sum = summation[i];
        insert((char)sum);
        display();
    }

    char removeList[] = {'B', 'S', 'A', 'O', 'R', 'K', 'Y', 'U', 'L', '\0'};
    i = 0;

    // insert again
    char addList[] = "ZPSLVMBCT";
    i = 0;
    while ((key = addList[i]) != '\0')
    {
        insert(key);
        display();
        i++;
    }
    key = 'x';
    index = 2;
    insertAfter(key, index);
    printf(xyz-1\n");
    int length = len();
    printf("xyz-2\n");

    // printf("\ninsert %c after index %d: (%d)\n", key, index, length);
    display();
}

/* Initialize the list. */
void init()
{
    head = NULL;
}
int len()
{
    struct node *tmp = head;
    int length = 0;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        length++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return length;
}
/* Print the content of the list. */
void display()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    struct node *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {

        current = current->next; // current = *(current).next;

    } //printf( "\n" );
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->prev; // current = *(current).prev;
    }
}

void insert(char c) //  at the end
{
    /* special case: list is empty, need to change head  */
    if (head == NULL)
    { /* the list is empty */
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->data = c;
        head->next = NULL;
        head->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        struct node *last = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        last->data = c;
        last->next = NULL;
        last->prev = tmp;
        tmp->next = last;
    }
}

void insertAfter(char c, int index)
{

    struct node *tmp = head;
    int currIndex = 0;
    while (tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        if (currIndex == index)
            break;

        currIndex++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    if (currIndex == index)
    {
        struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newNode->data = c;
        newNode->prev = tmp;
        newNode->next = tmp->next;
        struct node *nextNode = tmp->next;
        if (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp->next = &newNode;
            nextNode->prev = &newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you please edit your question by including the definition of `struct node`?

Comment: It is weird that an address starts with `0x7fff` is among addresses starts with `0x5555`. Maybe a pointer to non-static local variable whose life has already ended is used?

Comment: There doesn't _appear to be_ to be anything wrong with the code. The issue is probably in how you build the list. Please add that code.

Comment: If `current->next` or `current->prev` are invalid pointers, this would certainly happen.  Show how the list is initialized.  My guess is that `head->prev` is not properly set to NULL.

Comment: I have added the MWE. The weird thing is if I comment the line `    int length = len();` I don't get the `segmentation fault`

Comment: In `insertAfter()`, at `tmp->next = &newNode; nextNode->prev = &newNode;` you are storing the address of the pointer. Should be `tmp->next = newNode; nextNode->prev = newNode;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks My Bad I should have been careful there. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved your problem. The issue is in your `insertAfter` function, where you declare `struct node newNode`. This creates an object on the **stack**, while the rest of your list is stored on the **heap**. When the `insertAfter` function exits, this causes the stack to be unwound and the memory to be inaccessible. You should replace this line with a call to `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I replaced it with `struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` But I am still getting segmentation fault

Comment: Could you update the MRE please? And have you tried using GDB to figure out where you're getting the error?

Comment: Have updated the MRE. Nopes haven't tried using GDB

Comment: A side question. When we use malloc to allocate space it goes to the heap. So that won't be freed until we manually do free(ptr) right? Even after the function exits or till the program is running the memory will be reserved?

Comment: Yes. All memory allocated by `malloc` is preserved until the process terminates unless `free` is called.